# 10 coupons are given to 20 shoppers in a store. Each shopper can receive at most one coupon.

Tags: combinatorics

10 coupons are given to 20 shoppers in a store. Each shopper can receive at most
one coupon. 5 of the shoppers are women and 15 of the shoppers are men.

a. (5 pt.) If the coupons are identical, how many different ways are there to distribute
the coupons so that at least one woman receives a coupon?

b. (5 pt.) If the coupons are different, how many different ways are there to distribute
the coupons so that at least one woman receives a coupon?

**My work**

a) $\binom{20}{10}$ - $\binom{15}{10}$

b) $\binom{20}{10}$ - $\binom{5}{5}$$\binom{15}{5}$

Please verify my work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like (a) is right.  For (b), I suspect they want you to consider the event that at least one of Coupon A, Coupon B, Coupon C, etc., through Coupon J goes to one of the women.  So you should be looking at permutations, rather than combinations.

Comment: (a) is correct.  (b) you have neglected to account for the fact that the coupons are different.  If I were one of those shoppers... if I got a coupon for 10 cents off of a jar of peanut butter this would be very different than if I got a coupon for a free 80-inch LCD TV.  Further, what you calculated was the answer to if coupons are identical and we wanted to count how many ways we can distribute coupons such that at least one woman *didn't* receive a coupon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part a, you've done it correctly.

For part b, you can start with your logic from part a in that you can distribute the coupons to the $20$ people in $\binom{20}{10}$ ways, but need to account for the fact that the coupons are different. Between the $10$ people who each received a coupon, we can order these coupons $10!$ ways, so the total number of ways to distribute the coupons in part b is $\binom{20}{10} * 10!$, or $20$ permute $10$.

Using a similar method, you can calculate the number of ways the coupons could be distributed among just the men and find your answer.